# python mock functions with parameters

Tags: python, mocking

I want to mock a function that calls an external function with parameters.
I know how to mock a function, but I can't give parameters. I tried with @patch, side_effects, but no success.

```
def functionToTest(self, ip):
    var1 = self.config.get(self.section, 'externalValue1')
    var2 = self.config.get(self.section, 'externalValue2')
    var3 = self.config.get(self.section, 'externalValue3')

    if var1 == "xxx":
        return False
    if var2 == "yyy":
        return False

    [...]
```

In my test I can do this:

```
    def test_functionToTest(self):
    [...]
    c.config = Mock()
    c.config.get.return_value = 'xxx'
```

So both var1, var2 and var3 take "xxx" same value, but I don't know how to mock every single instruction and give var1, var2 and var3 values I want

(python version 2.7.3)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `side_effect` to queue up a series of return values.

```
c.config = Mock()
c.config.get.side_effect = ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']
```

The first time `c.config.get` is called, it will return `'xxx'`; the second time, `'yyy'`; and the third time, `'zzz'`. (If it is called a fourth time, it will raise a `StopIteration` error.)

Comment: Hey chepner, it works! I was trying change parameters (self.section, 'externalValue') but your solution was better. Thanks!